# Set animation direction via Javascript/Typescript

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, animation

Through Typescript I have to set an animation in a component defined in the html template.

To do this I am using the "animate (keyframes, options)" method.

In the options I would like to set the "alternate" direction but I don't know how to do it because the property is of type Playbackdirection which is an interface. How can I do it?

Here my code:

```
animate() {

const progress = document.querySelector(".progress") as HTMLElement;

if (progress !== null){
  const options = {
    duration: 2000,
    easing: "ease-in-out",
    iterations: 2,
    direction: "alternate" //ERROR HERE
  }

  progress.animate({
    width: ["0%", "10%", "20%", "30%", "40%", "50%", "60%", "70%", "80%", "80%", "80%"],
    backgroundSize: ["0%", "1000%", "500%", "333%", "250%", "200%", "166%", "142%", "125%", "125%", "125%"]
  }, options);
}
```

}

Comment: What does the error say exactly? "alternate" should be registered: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/2ef3901940894064fd933a8de5b1c0d2a2262884/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L18813

Comment: Type '{ duration: number; easing: string; iterations: number; direction: string; }' is not assignable to type 'KeyframeAnimationOptions'.
    Types of property 'direction' are incompatible.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'PlaybackDirection | undefined'.

@Kaiido

Comment: Interesting I get it to complain about the lack of type for `options` but once I pass  `options:KeyframeAnimationOptions = {` I get no complain anymore. Which version of TS are you using?

Comment: Angular: 13.3.11

Comment: Kind of weird I admit, but doing either `const options:KeyframeAnimationOptions = { ...` or `const direction:PlaybackDirection = "alternate"; const options = { ..., direction};` should do. But I'll let someone with better TS-fu than me explain why it wasn't able to walk 'til PlaybackDirection alone.

Comment: const direction:PlaybackDirection = "alternate"; woks for me. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

`direction: "alternate" as PlaybackDirection`,

Answer (score -1):

`direction` is an `enum`, so you should set it to `"normal"` or `"reverse"`.

```js
const options = {
  ...
  direction: "reverse"
}
```